# как достать из массива другой массив в React Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

У меня есть json

```
[
{
  id: 1,
  discipline: {
    ...
  },
  teacher: {
    ...
  },
  group: {
    ...
  },
  streamId: null,
  journalHeaders: [
    {
      id: 1,
      subGroup: 1,
      classTopic: null,
      discription: null,
      dateOfLesson: "10.12.2021",
      hoursCount: null,
      typeClass: {
        id: 1,
        name: "Лабораторная работа",
      },
      journalContents: [
        {
          id: 1,
          presence: true,
          grade: 6,
          discription: null,
          student: {
            id: 1,
            surname: "Седова",
            name: "Мария",
            patronymic: "Петровна",
            subGroup: 1,
          },
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          presence: false,
          grade: 8,
          discription: null,
          student: {
            id: 2,
            surname: "Липская",
            name: "Анна",
            patronymic: "Григорьевна",
            subGroup: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
},
];
```

Я хочу достать из него journalHeaders, вот что я делаю

```js
case SET_JOURNAL_HEADER:
  let newJournalsite = [...state.journalsite];
  let jHeader = [...state.journalHeader];
  newJournalsite[0].journalHeaders.map((header) => {
    jHeader.push(header);
  });
  return {
    ...state,
    journalHeader: jHeader,
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Извиняюсь ошибка была в том что я забыл передать journalHeader на страницу где его вызываю.